# How to fix "The target "ResolvePackageDependenciesDesignTime" does not exist in the project."

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to open a C# in VScode from Unity using the F# extension to open the csproj
yet I am getting the error

**Error:**
Build started. Project "Assembly-CSharp.csproj" (ResolvePackageDependenciesDesignTime;_GenerateCompileDependencyCache;CoreCompile target(s)): Building with tools version "Current". The target "ResolvePackageDependenciesDesignTime" does not exist in the project. Done building project "Assembly-CSharp.csproj" -- FAILED. Build FAILED.

I did install the .Net SDK (v5.0.302)
and the .Net Framework SDK (v4.7.1)

Any help is of course welcome!